# Toolbar icon in my winapi application become too small in high resolution

Tags: windows, winapi, icons, screen-resolution

I am very new in winapi development. I have built application which looks good otherwise but on running under bootcamp (mac book pro) with resolution 2880*1800, toolbar icon become too small. Application's icon also looks stretched.
From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
I understand that I have to make my application DPI aware. I followed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd464659(v=vs.85).aspx to create a sample application but toolbar icons and images used in wizards still look small.

I have used .ico with 32*32 and 16*16 size. So my question is-How to make my application look same in every screen resolution? This is my first question  on stackoverflow so I might have missed many details. Please let me know if more detail is needed about my application. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Use different sized icons based on the user's font scaling

Comment: Thanks, But how you suggest this solution to be generic. I have to create lot many resolution of icons. Even i do so what size of icon you suggest on 2880*1800 resolution.

Comment: The resolution is not important. It's the font scaling that counts.